# Selecting by element type then class name - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my HTML I have multiple empty divs and I would like to select every `div` with the class `highlight` using the query `$("input.highlight:div")` but it returns an error and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<div>Div 1</div>
<div class="highlight">Div 2</div>
<div id="third">Div 3</div>
<div class="highlight">Div 4</div>
```

Comment: By having `input` in the beginning you are selecting the `input` form fields. `$("div.highlight")` will work. It was just a typo.

Comment: The error is because `:` is a pseudo selector eg `:checked` - there's no selector for `:div`, it's just `div` giving `$("div.highlight")` (as others have stated, wanted to add info on the error which was missing)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.
first select div then use a class with it

```
$("div.highlight")
```

or if you have **.highlight** on div you can directly select that div using that class name.

```
$(".highlight")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var highlightsDiv=$("div.highlight")
 console.log(highlightsDiv.length)
 highlightsDiv.css({"color":"green"})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Div 1</div>
<div class="highlight">Div 2</div>
<div id="third">Div 3</div>
<div class="highlight">Div 4</div>
<div class="highlight">Div 5</div>
```